# Appending data to div tag inside content using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I am trying [twitter pagination](http://www.thetutorialblog.com/php/twitter-like-pagination-using-codeigniter-and-jquery/) in using JQuery. I have a search page (contains form) which will query the database and display it in the search results page.

When I am trying to hit the div tag (More button in the below page) in the below code, it should append only the data to `#results` instead the entire page is loading along with `#content` the appended data which looks same page overlapping one over the other. The logic of loading the data from the database and loading appropriate results when I hit `More` button. The only problem is displaying the results properly

Here is my code

```
<body>
    <?php $this->load->view('includes/topbar'); ?>
    <?php $this->load->view('includes/menu'); ?>      
    <?php $this->load->view('includes/left'); ?>        

  <div id="contentwrap">
    <div id="content">

        <div id="results">
                <?php
                foreach($this->data['latest_messages'] as $message)
                {
                    echo $message->uacc_email . ' - ' . '<br />';
                }
                ?>
        </div>
    <div id="more_button">
        More
    </div>
  </div>     
  </div>
    <?php $this->load->view('includes/right'); ?>   
    <?php $this->load->view('includes/foot'); ?> 
 </body>
```

Here is the code for my jquery in `<head>` section. The `auth_public/get_results/` will get the results from database.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
      var num_messages = <?=$num_messages?>;
      var loaded_messages = 0;
        $("#more_button").click(function(){
            loaded_messages += 10;
            $.get("<?php echo $base_url;?>" + "auth_public/get_results/" + loaded_messages, function(data){
                $("#results").append(data);

            });

            if(loaded_messages >= num_messages - 10)
            {
                $("#more_button").hide();
                //alert('hide');
            }
        })
    })
</script>
```

I have tried using span. But no luck the behavior is same. Any one help on this?

Comment: Have you looked in devtools to see what the ajax call is returning? Sounds like it is returning a full html page and you need to extract the content of `#results` before appending.

Comment: And post up the code from get_messages.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your problem with the `get_results`, i guess it returns output as html instead of json output as "jammykam" mentioned

go to `auth_public` look for the function `get_results` and replace the output line that should look like this `$this->load view($your_view,$data);`

or this `$this->parser->parse($your_view,$data);`

with `echo json_encode($data);`

Comment: Cool..It works fine but its displaying the entire json object. How can I reformat?

Comment: @Vikram use parseJSON() of jquery

Comment: sorry for the late reply, you could loop the data in an array inside your `get`  ex : `var length = data.length;
for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  $("#results").append(data[i]);
}`